# Tensorflow MNIST - accuracy of particular test image

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

Here is the code that I used for predicting particular mnist image, how can i get accuracy by which the prediction is done ?

_pre are logits

```
    _x  = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
    _y  = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('y:0')
    _pre  = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prediction:0')
    p = tf.argmax(_pre, 1)
    i = imageprepare('./image.png')
    print(p.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that "accuracy" means "the probability that was assigned to the selected label". From your code it is unclear how `_pre` was created. If it consist of the probability vectors (that is, `softmax` was already applied) then you can get the accuracy as follows:

```
acc=tf.reduce_max(_pre, 1)
print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}))
```

The reason is that `p` was the location of the maximal probability, while the accuracy (`acc` in this case) is the maximal probability itself.

If `_pre` consists of the logits vectors (that is, if applying `softmax` on `_pre` will give the probability vectors),

then this will do the job:

```
acc=tf.reduce_max(tf.nn.softmax(_pre), 1)
print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}))
```

Comment: how can i print this accuracy? i mean i want this output => predicted number is 5 with accuracy 0.6

Comment: print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})) this prints the predicted number

Comment: Wait, didn't you say that print(p.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})) prints the predicted number (label)?

Comment: yes i said it but i also want to print the accuracy , is this output possible => "number predicted is 4 with accuracy 0.6" ? i am newbie , let me know if my question is wrong

Comment: So just to make sure, when you run print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})), do you get a number between 0 to 1?

Comment: If the answer to the above comment is yes, you could print it by doing: print("number predicted is %d with accuracy %f" %(p.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}),acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})))

Comment: print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})) , i get number from 0 to 9

Comment: And what do you get when you do print(p.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})) ?

Comment: look 'print(p.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}))' gives me 0-9  and this line gives error 'acc=tf.max(_pre, 1)' that max is not a tensorflow function , or something like that

Comment: Sorry it should be acc=tf.reduce_max(_pre, 1) (see my updated answer). What do you get now when you do print(acc.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]})) ?

Comment: [18607.91796875] , i got this

Comment: isnt it weird ?

Comment: It sound like _pre is the vector that you have before the softmax, but without seeing how it is produced (and the code you gave does not provide this information) I can't know for sure. If this is indeed the case, then I think this should work: acc=tf.reduce_max(tf.nn.softmax(_pre),1)

Comment: for every image i tested i am now getting this '[ 1.]'

Comment: This is not nessecarily bad news. If _pre is defined as I thought, it just means that the network gives probability 1 (or extremely close to 1) to the correct label. But in order to be sure that this is what happening I'll need to see the entire code. Could you post the full code in your question? Including how _pre was created? Also, what do you get when you run print(_pre.eval(feed_dict={_x: [i]}))